# Is WebApi lighter than WCF REST?

Tags: c#, json, rest, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I know this could be the duplicate question or boring question but I need to know the answer as this is the biggest platform I can have to ask question.

I was searching for the difference between WebApi and WCF REST and in almost every article I found that WebApi is lighter than WCF REST but none of them told "why". All are talking about SOAP vs REST or XML vs JSON or HTTP vs Other protocols but no one clearly said why WebApi is lighter than WCF REST.

As per my understanding(very small knowledge) both work over HTTP protocol and can return JSON data (it supposed to be lighter than XML). If protocol and return data type both are same than what make WebApi lighter? or In other words, **if you need JSON data and Rest ful serice which one you prefer WebApi or WCF Rest and why?**

Comment: WCF does a *lot* more than just HTTP/JSON.  This is sort of like asking why a car is lighter than a dump truck when they both have wheels.  It isn't lighter because of shared characteristics, its lighter because of what they *don't share*.

Comment: Please read: https://blog.tonysneed.com/2016/01/06/wcf-is-dead-long-live-mvc-6/

Comment: wcf is a complete framework used for communication across various protocols and channels. you can read more about wcf on msdn, but if your need is only json, then web api is the right way to go.

Comment: Unless you define "light" in a more meaningful way, this is not answerable.

Comment: If you want to go a step further, Nancy is lighter than webAPI.

Comment: @Ash why WebApi is is right way in case of JSON?

Comment: @LexLi to be honest with you I am not quite sure about this "light". As per my understanding, it is related to performance and resouce using.

Comment: @TomRedfern I never heard about Nancy. Actually I need to know the answer between these two only. Could you please help me on the same.

Comment: Only a few points are available but this might help you 
-Web Api supports only http.  
-WCF service can be used for many protocols by exposing it with various endpoints. 
-Web Api may be one or two(CORS,Camel to Pascal Case,etc) which are not mandatory. 
-WCF you need make a lot of configurations which are mandatory. 
-Web Api reduces 80% of the coding time as major code is auto generated.
-WCF you need to start from scratch.
**and so on**

Comment: @Sunil20000 ASP.NET branches out two different frameworks, namely, ASP.NET MVC (primarily used for processing data + html) and ASP.NET WebAPI (primarily used for data ONLY). JSON is one format of shaping your data due to obvious reasons of Javascript native support for JSON and IF it has to be consumed in a web client. You can go with other formats, like XML, etc entirely depends upon your requirements.

Comment: @Aravind Thanks man.

Comment: @ash thanks ash, I get it now.